# Consulta set update codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

tengo el siguiente inconveniente soy nuevo en codeigniter y no se com o puedo hacer esta consulta es actualizar y eliminar, Actualizar un registro en tabla productos y eliminar en tabla entradas. Elimino bien pero no se como actualizar restando el valor del campo a una variable. Adjunto código del controlador y el modelo Desde ya muchas gracias

// el controlador delent() recibe los parametros y con "id" hago la consulta para obtener la cantidad y lo paso al metodo  updaten() del modelo.

```
  public function delent() {
        $id_area = $this->input->post('id_area');
        $id = $this->input->post('id');

        $sql = "SELECT cantidad_ent FROM entradas where entradas.id_entrada = '$id'";
        $this->mreportes->updaten($sql);
        $query1 = $this->mreportes->delent($id_area, $id);

    }
```

// metodo updaten() del modelo mreportes

```
 function updaten($sql) {
        $data = $this->db->query($sql);
        $this->db->set('stock_actual', stock_actual - $data);
          $this->db->update('productos');
    return true;
    }
```

Necesito que el campo stock_actual se actualice a stock_actual - $data. Gracias